# Field Calculator extract three last digits from another field

Tags: field-calculator, qgis-2.2

How everyone!

I have two fields the on is the cadastral number which is for example 051020213001 and I am trying to fill the other field (label) with the last 3 digits from the cadastral number, in this case 001. Is there any way I can do that automatically and not manually because I have 2800 polygons in which I have to do that. I am using QGIS 2.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fields containing the number are of the same length,

```
substr( tostring("fieldname"),10,3)
```

should work in the field calculator.